# In Neo4j can I return only one matching node to calculate an average value?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Hi I don't even know how to properly describe this, apologies for the terrible title:

I have Users who write Posts which can have Ratings and those Ratings are tied to Movies. I'd like to calculate the average ratings, but currently a single user is counting multiple times. Is it possible to find the most recent post by a specific user that has a rating and ONLY use that one in the calculation, but do that for every user who has a post with a rating for that movie? Essentially I'd like to take all users' most recent ratings and average those.

I currently have this:

```
MATCH (Movie { name: "The Dark Knight"})-[:HAS_RATING]-(r:Rating)-[]-(p:Post)-[]-(u:User)
WITH DISTINCT u, avg(r.value) AS ratingAverage, r
RETURN apoc.math.round(ratingAverage, 2)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How do you know which post is the most recent?

Comment: Hi @TomažBratanič that would be `post.created_date`. I'm not sure where I would even use it!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so if you want to only look at the latest post by a user, and then calculate the average rating of the latest review, you have a couple of options:

Using subqueries:

```
MATCH (u:User)
// get the latest post
CALL {WITH u 
  MATCH (u)--(p:Post)
  WITH u,p 
  ORDER BY p.created_date DESC
  RETURN p LIMIT 1
}
WITH u,p
MATCH (p)-[:HAS_RATING]-(r:Rating)
RETURN apoc.math.round(avg(r.value),2) as average_value
```

You could also use collect and then use list slicing to get the latest post:

```
MATCH (u:User)--(p:Post)
// order posts by date
WITH u,p
ORDER BY p.created_date DESC
// get the latest post
WITH u, collect(p)[0] as latest
MATCH (latest)-[:HAS_RATING]-(r:Rating)
RETURN apoc.math.round(avg(r.value),2) as average_value
```

You are essentially limiting results per each row, you can check the knowledge base article and see all possible approaches: https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/limiting-match-results-per-row/

Comment: Holy smokes that worked immediately! Which do you think would be more performant? Does it matter? This is incredible, thanks a ton!

Comment: And one more question, is the first one going to go through every single user, rather than just the users who have written posts that have that Movie tagged? Should I specify like this?: `MATCH (u)--(p:Post)-[:TAGGED]-(t:Thing { name: "The Dark Knight"})`

Comment: Subqueries will also reduce cardinality afaik, i am not sure what your schema looks like, but you can add additional filters for matching reviews. As for performance, use the PROFILE clause to evaluate